# Wordpress SideOffer Closing on body click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This is the jQuery code written on the php file of the plugin. IT is working fine now but i want it to close when some one clicks outside of the panel.

Here is the javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* SideOffer Sidebar Functionality */
    $("#sideoffer").toggle(
        function() { $(this).animate({ "right": "<?php echo get_option('hd_sideoffer_out'); ?>px" }, "slow"); },
        function() { $(this).animate({ "right": "<?php echo get_option('hd_sideoffer_in'); ?>px" }, "slow"); }
    );


    /* SideOffer .hd-sideoffer click function */
    $(".sideoffer").click(function(){ $("#sideoffer").click(); });
    /* SideOffer aLlow clicks on content box */
    $("#sideoffer .box").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });

});</script>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is add this into the `ready` function

What it does is adding a `delegated` event on the document to trigger when anything that is `not` `#sideoffer` is cclicked and then `hide` `#sideoffer`.

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(#sideoffer)', function(){ 
    $('#sideoffer').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the click event for everything other than your original click, which I guess is `#sideoffer`?

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#sideoffer').length) {
        $('#sideoffer').animate({ "right": "<?php echo get_option('hd_sideoffer_in'); ?>px" }, "slow");
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy :D !! It worked!!. If only i could understand javascript and jquery like you do :(

Comment: Facing a issue that now to open the slide i have to double click it and also i want one more change that if within say 15 second nothing happens inside the div then it should close automatically. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

try to use javascript

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    /* do something when getting element you are currently click on*/
}
```

Here is example, http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: The OP was using javascript to begin with, what you're referencing is jQuery !